# My function is stopping at a specific point

Tags: c

```
void changeSubstringCase(char str[], char a[]) {
/**
* If `a` is a substring of `str`, then change the case (capitalization) of
* the corresponding substring in `str`. Special characters (' ', '.', ...)
* do not need to be handled. You should only change the letters.
*
* For example:
*
*    char str[100] = "This IS a SENTence WITH BAd CAPITalizaTION";
*    changeSubstringCase(str, "IS a SENTence WI");
*    printf("%s\n", str);
*   
* should print out "This is A sentENCE wiTH BAd CAPITalizaTION".
*/
int slen = 0;
int alen = 0;
int scount = 0;
int counter = 0;
char alpha[1024] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
char Calpha[1024] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
slen = strlen(str);

alen = strlen(a);
for(int i = 0; i < slen; i++)
{
   //printf("a\n");
   if(a[counter] == str[i])
   {
       counter++;
       if(counter == alen)
       {
           //printf("l\n");
            scount = i - counter;
            break;
       }
   }
   else
   {
       counter = 0;
   }
}
printf("Bad boy\n");    
if(counter != alen)
{
    printf("bye\n");
    return;
}
int m = 0;
int f = 0;
while(a[m] != '\0')
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 26; i++)
    {
        if(a[m] == alpha[i])
        {
            printf("a\n");
            a[m] = Calpha[i];
            break;
        }
        else if(a[m] == Calpha[i])
        {
            printf("b\n");
            a[m] = alpha[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    m++;
}
for(int i = 0; i < alen; i++)
{
   printf("hel");
   str[scount] = a[i];
   scount++;
}

return;  // Not returning anything. `str` is modified directly.
}
int main() {
char str[MAX_STRING_LEN] = "CSCA48 Exercise 1";

// This should replace the substring:
replaceSubstring(str, "A48 Ex", "A48 sUMMER 2020 Ex");

// This should NOT replace anything, since some of the letters
// in `a` have a different capitalization than in the string, so it is
// NOT a valid substring.
replaceSubstring(str, "summer 2020", "Winter 2020");

// This should change the capitalization of the substring:
changeSubstringCase(str, "sUMMER 2020");

// This should NOT change the capitalization, since the corresponding letters
// in `a` are lowercase, and it is not a valid substring.
changeSubstringCase(str, "csca48");

printf("Expected result: \"CSCA48 sUMMER 2020 Exercise 1\"\n");
printf("Your solution: \"%s\"\n", str);
return 0;
}
```

for some reason the code stops int the nested for loop conditional statement. I have tested all I can but I cannot see the problem as to why it would stop after that point. Especially because all im doing is trying to replace the alphabet with the capital counter part.

Any Help would be appreciated.

I am new to programming so anything complex will be wasted on me

Comment: what did you see when you stepped through with your debugger

Comment: it literally just stopped, it didnt go back to the main function, it just stopped and command control asked me my next command.

Comment: because you are not returning anything, you're just returning.. try return and something you want to return, for example a value

Comment: Im just modifying a string and returning is uneccessary. especially cuz its a void function.

Comment: what did you see when you stepped through with your debugger? Do you know how to use a debugger?

Comment: also , can we see all the code please, how you call it

Comment: I do not know how to use a debugger

Comment: learn to use your debugger, it will take 15 mins. Life gets a lot easier then,

Comment: `void changeSubstringCase(char str[], char a[])` You should change the second argument to `const char a[]` because the function is not supposed to modify it. Then the compiler will warn you that the code is trying to write to a constant string.

Comment: we do not have the replaceSubstring function

Answer (score 0):

you return from your code because after the first loop  `counter != alen` and so you print 'bye' and return.

I am not sure what you are trying to do but thats why it 'stops' for no apparent reason.

PS - I found this using my debugger (gdb in this case)

Comment: I am not sure if that is it, considering I put the print statement there to check if the function reaches that if statement, which it doesnt in all my trials. Also that if statement exists to return to main function before making any changes on the chance that it a is not a substring of str.

Comment: well i ran your code in my debugger and thats what happens,  did you run it in your debugger

Comment: no, but I can guarantee that is not the problem, cuz i took the statement out, still same problem